# Pyhon django как при нажатии на тег button выводить текст принадлежищий к определенной строке в базе данных

Tags: python, html, django, аудио, button

`Pyhon django` как при нажатии на тег `button` выводить текст принадлежащий к определенной строке в базе данных

В бд есть две строки `title` и `musiclink`
мне нужно что бы при нажатии на `button` содержимое `musiclink` попадало в тег `audio src=`

```html
<div class="searc11_22">
    <audio src="" controls></audio>
    {% for vb in music %}
        <div class="musicct">
            <h3>{{ vb.title }}</h3>
            <button onclick="">Play</button>
            <a href="{{ vb.musiclink }}">ff</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Если мой ответ помог тебе, пожалуйста, пометь его как верный. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В тег `audio` добавь класс `player`.
2. В тег `button` обработчику `onclick` дай следующую конструкцию `document.querySelector('.player').src = {{ vb.musiclink }}`

Должно получиться нечто вроде такого.

```html
<div class="searc11_22">
    <audio class="player" src="" controls></audio>
    {% for vb in music %}
        <div class="musicct">
            <h3>{{ vb.title }}</h3>
            <button 
                onclick="document.querySelector('.player').src = {{ vb.musiclink }}"
            >Play</button>
            <a href="{{ vb.musiclink }}">ff</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Вот пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dko7cu2x/6/). Примерно то, что получиться на выходе с Django для 3 треков. Звуковые дорожки взял рандомные для примеры.